# Can i cross-fade li elements using angularjs ngAnimate

Tags: css, angularjs, html-lists, ng-animate

I am trying to understand angularJS and have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petervannes/sd61516o/19/) written, which is a very simple message ticker.

The messages are shown by changing the CSS display attribute of one of the li elements.

```
    <div id="ngtickerMessage"  class="ngtickerMessage">
        <ul >
            <li ng-style="{display:setVisible($index)}" data-ng-repeat="msgObj in msgs track by $index">{{msgObj.msg}}</li> 
        </ul>
     </div> 
</div>
```

Is it possible to (cross-) fade the contents of the li element based on ngAnimate using the ng-style attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `opacity` instead of `display` in the `ng-style` of `li` and added a CSS `transition` to it. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqubkx3k/)**. Hope it helps.